# How to get last li with certain class in ul-li list with different li classes

Tags: css

I have ul-li list

```
<ul>
<li class="digit">1</li>
<li class="digit">2</li>
<li class="digit">3</li>
<li class="letter">A</li>
<li class="letter">B</li>
</ul>
```

Can I get with pure css last selector '.digit' in list? Quantity of .digit is unknown `ul li.digit:nth-last-child(-n+1){ background: red; }` doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use:

```
.digit:nth-child(3) {color:red;}
```

```css
.digit:nth-child(3) {color:red;}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="digit">1</li>
<li class="digit">2</li>
<li class="digit">3</li>
<li class="letter">А</li>
<li class="letter">Б</li>
</ul>
```

However, if there's going to be an unknown number of "digit" class as you post in your comment, you may need to use a bit of javascript /jquery like this:

```js
  $('.digit:last').addClass( "newclass" );
```

```css
.newclass {color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="digit">1</li>
<li class="digit">2</li>
<li class="digit">3</li>
<li class="digit">4</li>
<li class="digit">5</li>
<li class="letter">А</li>
<li class="letter">Б</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but quantity of .digit is unknown

Comment: Edited my answer. Check it out

Comment: with pure css. I know how to do with jquery, need pure css solution

Comment: there is not a pure css solution